# How do I get the img tag "src" value from a Selenium Web Browser element as a string?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium and i'm trying to get the "src" value from a `IWebElement` and convert it to a string (C#). I am able to get a simple text value from elements using their built in `.Text`, but that will only give me the inner html. Here's the sample code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();            
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://somewebsite");        
var val = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("img"));
string imageSrc = ?????
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `GetAttribute()` method:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("img"));
string imageSrc = element.GetAttribute("src")
```

Answer (score 0):

use xPath, for example

```
//img[@src='The image src']
```

Also you can use `assert.istru` and `.Displayed`